# Cannot find a class with the main method

Tags: java

me mandaron este codigo hecho con JAVA que es de sumar y multiplicar dos numero que ingresa el usuario pero al momento de compilar sale el mensaje **"Cannot find a class with the main method"** o **"Error: Could not find or load main class tempCodeRunnerFile
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tempCodeRunnerFile"**. y ya verifique que el nombre del .java sea el mismo que el de la clase. Lo probe tanto en netbeans, replit, visual studio y no se que es que falta o que es lo que esta mal escrito para que no funcione.

##### contexto de como funciona el cogido:

El código cuenta con una clase base llamada RetoX, un objeto de tipo Scanner y un par de métodos.
El método read() nos servirá para solicitar datos al usuario. El método run() funcionará como
nuestro método principal (en este caso remplaza al método main()). Se llama al método run() para realizar la ejecución del programa. Podemos declarar tantos métodos como necesitemos dentro de la clase RetoX, e incluso declarar otras clases (siempre que no sean públicas). utilizar el método read() para leer datos. No debemos declarar otras variables de tipo Scanner dentro del programa.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/*
* Recomendaciones Generales:
*
*    -> El método run() funcionará como nuestro método principal
*    -> No declarar objetos de tipo Scanner, utilizar el método read() para solicitar datos al usuario.
*    -> Si requiere utilizar varias clases, estas NO deben ser tipo public.
*/
class Reto0{

    private final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public String read(){
        return this.scanner.nextLine();
    }

    public void run(){

        String[] Nums = this.read().split(" ");

        int Num1 = Integer.parseInt(Nums[0]);
        int Num2 = Integer.parseInt(Nums[1]);

        double suma = Num1 + Num2;
        double multi = Num1 * Num2;

        System.out.println(suma+" "+multi);
        System.out.println(Nums);
    }
}
```

Comment: siempre es necesario el método main para ejecutar un programa en java

Answer (score 0):

Es porque no tienes la clase main, si no tienes ese método tu programa no va a correr. El metodo run no puede sustituir al main, puedes crear otra clase Main e instancias un objeto de la clase Reto0 y así puedes llamar al metodo run().

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reto0 reto= new Reto0();
        reto.run();
    }
    
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: como se haria eso? en que parte del codigo añado el que enviaste o toca hacer un nuevo archivo para ejecutar el tuyo? sorry soy nuevo en esto y no entiendo nada

Comment: Crea otra clase en tu mismo proyecto( Donde esta el icono de una carpeta que tiene el nombre de tu proyecto, clic izquierdo, luego New >>Class) y copias ese código. Tienes que tener dos clases en tu proyecto: clase Main y la clase reto0